# Compare XML files from two folders

Tags: java, python, xml, groovy, compare

Is there anyway to compare XML files (having same name) saved in two different folders and find the difference between them? I would like to compare multiple XML files stored in different folders for testing purposes. I'm happy to explore this in any language such as Java, Groovy script, python etc.,

Please add your thoughts. Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the definition of difference? XML-wise or binary- or text-wise?

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

[filecmp: File and Directory Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html):

```
import filecmp
cmp = filecmp.cmp('file_1.xml', 'file_2.xml')

# Files are equal
if cmp:
    continue
else:
    out_file.write('file_1.xml')
```

Comment: Clean and to the point for python. +1

Answer (score 2):

groovy with usage of xmlunit:

```groovy
@Grab(group='xmlunit', module='xmlunit', version='1.6')
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit 

XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
def r1 = new File('/11/1.xml').newReader("UTF-8")
def r2 = new File('/11/2.xml').newReader("UTF-8")
def diff = XMLUnit.compareXML(r1, r2)
assert diff.similar()
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is the first answer which does not consider XML files 'different' just because they differ binary-wise.

Answer (score 1):

For Java something like

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("aaa.xml");
        File file2 = new File("bbb.xml");
        boolean areTwoFilesEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2);
        System.out.println("Two files are equal?" + areTwoFilesEqual);
    }
```

would do the cause with Apache Commons IO API.

Answer (score 0):

You can  compare two XML files using TreeOps visual tool  https://github.com/treeops/treeops. It transforms and compares tree data in XML/JSON/CSV.
User can select paths to be ignored by comparison.

TreeOps defines set of data tree transformations to facilitate typical data manipulations:

- filtering and deleting irrelevant data
- renaming and moving nodes
  along the tree
- flattening and de-flattening to convert between tree and tabular formats
- change nodes using regular expressions under selected nodes